# Issues with inaccurate snapping and line weights

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, alignment, snapping, pixel-grid

This question is in two parts. First, I'm having trouble with line weights below 1 pt. I scaled a drawing with multiple lines and shapes, most of the strokes scaled to .1pt but the stroke on two shapes will not go below 1, maybe this is because they are shapes (made using the rounded rectangle tool) and not strokes? how do I make the shape stroke go below 1pt?

Second I've been having issues with inaccurate snapping. I've been working around the problem but the reason I put these two issues together is because answers for both types of questions on these forums point me to the transform panel with the align to pixel grid check box. Other people's snap and stroke problems seem to be fixed by unchecking this box but it doesnt work for me. I didn't have these issues before switching to CC, cant tell if its a bug or some box I need to check. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I'm using Illustrator CC (2015.3.0 Release)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure pixel preview is off!

Comment: It's already off but thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

I would scale the objects back up to the point where the strokes look as they should, then expand everything's appearance. This way, everything will remain consistent when resizing.

- Select everything <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Object > Expand

As for the snapping, I dunno.

Comment: I followed your steps but the stroke on the rounded rectangle still wont go below 1 pt. I redrew the shape with the pen tool and it scales below 1 pt so it must be something about the stoke on shapes. If you have any other ideas let me know but otherwise thanks for trying!

Answer (score 1):

You have to *select the object* and THEN uncheck Align to Pixel Grid on the Transform panel.

If the object happened to be drawn with the Pixel Grid snapping on, it'll stay on for that object until you disable it. After selecting the object and unchecking the Align to Pixel Grid, strokes should go below 1pt. And you'll also see alignments less restrictive.

For what it's worth, you *really* don't want to ever create strokes smaller than 0.25pt. A 0.1pt stroke will be lost on press.